# HTTP request in node.js returning response.statuscode as forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, header

I want to post data in a 3rd part website using nodejs but I keep getting the error 403.

I can use this in a browser, but it doesn't work on nodejs:

```
$.ajax("/login", 
  { 
    data: {
    username:"username",
    password: "password",
    },

    method:"POST"
   }).done(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
   });
```

It works fine. The problem starts when I try to use it in node.js, I keep getting the error 403 - forbidden. Thanks!

Edit: I was getting the error because of a (fairly common) privacy policy.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the response body of the failing HTTP request. It's possible that there's an error message.

Comment: There is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the jQuery code actually send the username and password as plaintext, or is it using Authorization? You can check in the browser console when you make the request. Typically user/password are sent as an Authorization header, you'll see something like "Authorization: Basic " in the headers of the request.

If so, you'll need to replicate that in Node as well. You can check out [the request documentation](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication) for more information how - it's quite simple.